Is it possible to solve this kind of quadratic simultaneous equations?
$$\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{N} \\
\mathbf{A}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}, 
\mathbf{b}_i  \in \mathbb{R}^N ,
\mathbf{c}_i  \in \mathbb{R}\\
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{x} +\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}_i+\mathbf{c}_i=0 \text{,  }i\in[1, N] \\\\$$
I thought this can be solved by lagrange multiplier method, but I realized that it can not be generally formulated so that it can be implemented into the program code. It is quite hard to find analytic solution or numerical algorithm to solve this kind of simultaneous quadratic system.

If you are looking for an exact solution, then I agree that the search for it can be unsuccessful, but If you need a numerical solution you can use standard numerical methods as Newton-Kantorovich (or better Newton-Raphson  since we are dealing with algebraic equations), thus I don't see the difficulty in dealing with this problem.

@DanieleTampieri Is it possible to apply Newton's method in a simultaneous system?

Sure, have a look at the relevant part of the associated Wikipedia entry and tho the cited reference, particularly the book of Demidovich and Maron.

Since one solves an equation, and not a kind of equation, I'd rather say "to solve quadratic simultaneous equations of this kind"

Assume that the $(A_i,b_i,c_i)$ are generic; for example, randomly choose their  entries.
Then, with probability $1$, there are exactly $2^N$ complex solutions.
More precisely, if we work over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can solve the system using Groebner basis theory; we obtain $\{P(x_1)=0, x_2=Q_2(x_1), \cdots, x_N=Q_N(x_1)\}$, where
$P\in\mathbb{Q}[t]$ has degree $2^N$ and $Q_i\in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ has degree $2^{N}-1$.
Unfortunately, the complexity of the algorithm is exponential:
For example , when the entries are in $[[-10..10]]$, the times of calculation $\Delta_N$ are as follows:
$\Delta_5=0"8, \Delta_6=31"2,\Delta_7=37'7"$.
On the other hand, there are few real solutions; for $N=6$, the mean is $\approx 7.8$ and the number varies generally between $4$ and $14$. Of course, if you are specially unlucky, you may have no solutions.
Finally, if $N\geq 10$, you can use a Newton's method over $\mathbb{R}$. Of course, you can randomly choose initial points and get a number of real solutions (the calculations are generally fast). However, you don't know if you got all the real solutions. Thus, I fear that you will have to calculate the $2^N$ solutions over $\mathbb{C}$ (Complex Newton's method; if $N=10$, then $2^N=1024$) if you want to be sure that you have not lost any solutions along the way.
